# Why `ParallelTable` doesn't work in this simple code?

Tags: list-manipulation, parallelization

The code

```
Table[{a[i] = i^2, b[i] = a[i] + 100}, {i, 1, 4}]
a[1]
a[2]
a[3]
a[4]
b[1]
b[2]
b[3]
b[4]
```

returns (correctly) the following output:

```
{{1, 101}, {4, 104}, {9, 109}, {16, 116}}
1
4
9
16
101
104
109
116
```

But if I use `ParallelTable` instead, I get

```
{{1, 101}, {4, 104}, {9, 109}, {16, 116}}
a[1]
a[2]
a[3]
a[4]
b[1]
b[2]
b[3]
b[4]
```

> What's hapanneing? I want to keep the definitions for `a[i]` and `b[i]`, $i=1,2,3,4$, and, still, `Parallelize` the `Table`.

Ps.: actually, I want to keep the definition of `b[i]`, $i=1,2,3,4$, only. I won't need the definitions of `a[i]`, $i=1,2,3,4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [`SetSharedFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetSharedFunction.html):

```
In[1]:= LaunchKernels[4]

Out[1]= {"KernelObject"[1, "local"], "KernelObject"[2, "local"], 
 "KernelObject"[3, "local"], "KernelObject"[4, "local"]}

In[2]:= SetSharedFunction[a, b]

In[3]:= ParallelTable[{a[i] = i^2, b[i] = a[i] + 100}, {i, 1, 4}]
{a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4]}

Out[3]= {{1, 101}, {4, 104}, {9, 109}, {16, 116}}

Out[4]= {1, 4, 9, 16, 101, 104, 109, 116}
```

Comment: Nice! I would ask if the problem could be related to `DistributedContexts`, but your solution works well.